# Swagger and Swashbuckle

Tags: .net-core, swagger

I'm trying to generate with .NET Core application a Swagger file to use with Swagger CodeGen.

I've tried UseAllOfToExtendRerefenceSchemas and it produces this output

```
"/api/services/app/ABC/GetXYZs": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "XYZ"
    ],
    "operationId": "GetXYZs",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "XYZInputType",
        "in": "query",
        "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/XYZType"
        }
      }
    ]
    }
```

The corresponding code generated by Swager CodeGen is
GetXYZs(XYZInputType xyzInputType = null)
that generates error since xyzInputType is not declared nullable.

From the other side I cannot use UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums because it breaks other client code.

I ended up trying to manually change the JSON to understand what Swagger CodeGen is expecting to act defining the variable as nullable. I tried with this code but it didn't work

```
"/api/services/app/ABC/GetXYZs": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "XYZ"
    ],
    "operationId": "GetXYZs",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "XYZInputType",
        "in": "query",
        "schema": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/XYZType"
            }
          ],
          "nullable": true
        }
      }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: *that generates error since xyzInputType is not declared nullable* - what type is xyzInputType?